# Why does this black line appear on the borders of projected shadows when using the shadowmap technique with transparencies?

Tags: c++, directx, shader

This is a screenshot of the problem: http://s13.postimg.org/672twurfr/shadowmap_saturn_rings.jpg

You can notice a black line on top of the projected shadows of the rings over saturn, it happens on all borders of the shadows of any object.

This is the pixel shader I'm using to render the depth map, I'm using the green and blue values of the color to store the alpha value.

```
float depthValue;
float4 color;
float4 textureColor;    

textureColor = shaderTexture.Sample(SampleType, input.tex);

depthValue = input.depthPosition.z / input.depthPosition.w;

color = float4(depthValue, textureColor.a, textureColor.a, 1.0f);

return color;
```

and this is the pixel shader fragment I'm using to render the final color that will be displayed:

```
if((saturate(projectTexCoord.x) == projectTexCoord.x) && (saturate(projectTexCoord.y) == projectTexCoord.y))
{
    float4 color_d = depthMapTexture.Sample(SampleTypeClamp, projectTexCoord);

    depthValue = color_d.r;

    lightDepthValue = input.lightViewPosition.z / input.lightViewPosition.w;

    lightDepthValue = lightDepthValue - bias;

    if(lightDepthValue < depthValue)
    {
        lightIntensity = saturate(dot(input.normal, lightDir));
    }

    else
    {
        lightIntensity = saturate(dot(input.normal, lightDir))*(1.0f - color_d.g);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the vague info, but I don't really have a clue of where the problem can be, maybe it's somewhere else in the code, but it's definitely not the texture file I'm using, so it's gotta be the code.

Any idea of where I can start looking for the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the texture filter used by the D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC, it was set to D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR, so the texture was being interpolated, kind of softening the colors and alpha values at the borders, which caused the shader to read those soft alpha values and cast shadows where it wasn't supposed to.

I created a new samplerdesc using D3D11_FILTER_COMPARISON_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT as the filter so the texture would be presented with the borders mostly unchanged, just as the depth shader created it originally. Now the shadows are cast properly with no weird black line at the borders anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Perphaps it's the shadowmap texture coordinates sampling out of bounds. I can see you are checking for that but I would test it anyway.
In your SamplerState, do you have a BorderColor set? Try setting it to red and see if that's the problem.

Does the shadow map have the same depth as the rendertarget you are applying the shader on?

Edit. This is my shader code with SampleCmpLevelZero:

```
if (ShadowCoord.x > 0.0f && ShadowCoord.x < 1.0f && ShadowCoord.y > 0.0f && ShadowCoord.y < 1.0f) 
    {
        ShadowCoord.z -= 0.001f;
        float a = 1;

        a = ShadowMap.SampleCmpLevelZero(ShadowSampler, ShadowCoord.xy, ShadowCoord.z).r;
        a = linearizeDepth(a);

        ambient = float4(a,a,a, 0);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefan Agartsson, those suggestions where among the first ones I checked for, but none of them was causing the issue. Although later i found it was actually related to the D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC, I'll put the details in the answer below.

Comment: When I check my own code I have COMPARISON_MIN_MAG_LINEAR_MIP_POINT set, sorry I could have pointed that out. But I also use SampleCmpLevelZero instead of just Sample in case you want to try it.

Comment: COMPARISON_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT seems to work much better in this scenario. I edited my answer already to mention that filter instead. I'll check SampleCmpLevelZero to see what happens. –